# Swagger : TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am trying to define a simple API which is pretty much an healthcheck.
My problem is that the requests is correct, the answer I receive from the server is correct, but it is not displayed by swagger : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBm8T.jpg

Here's what the answer I get (which is correct) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEJW8.jpg and the HTTP status is 200 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7M9y.jpg

Also,I have defined the HTTP status 200 and 500 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5ykr.jpg

Would anyone have a hint ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156665/swagger-ui-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-on-valid-response)?